# ASP.NET MVC request context details

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

Where can I plug in a custom provider to set up the request context?

I want to run an ASP.NET MVC application in "slave" mode while gradually transitioning features from a legacy system. Each request will have a cookie, and I want to grab the cookie, make an external call to resolve it to a user identity, and set up that user identity for the remainder of the request.

I might set a forms authentication cookie, or use Session, but the source of truth about authentication has to be the externally-set cookie, on every request.

What's the best way to do this? Where do I plug in? I've looked at Authentication providers, and the Authorization attribute, but neither of those seems the right place for this.

Comment: Perhaps the Global.asax in the Application_AuthenticateRequest method of your ASP.NET MVC app or in a Module.

Comment: That seems to be too late. From MSDN: This method is called to do any post-authentication handling by HttpApplication. I need to actually do the authentication, and create the User object.

Comment: Which you can do in the AuthenticateRequest method. You can update the  HttpContext.Current.User to be a custom Principal object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought an HttpModule would be ideal for this scenario?

If I understand you correctly, I did something similar on a project I was working  on recently:

```
  public class UserSessionHttpModule : IHttpModule
{

    private HttpApplication mApplication;

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        mApplication = context;
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(CheckUserSession);
    }

    private void CheckUserSession(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(mApplication.Context.Request.Path);

        if (extension == "" || extension == ".aspx")
        {
            var userSessionService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserSessionService>();
            userSessionService.CheckUserSession();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That does sound promising. I thought that an HttpModule would not have access to the ASP.NET context. What exactly do I need to set up for the request to proceed without knowing that the authentication is non-standard?

Comment: I implemented my own custom AuthorizeAttribute which I put on actions in order to authorize them using my own user session service. Can post code if it would help.

Comment: I really just want to know what Forms Authentication sets up, so I can make the custom authentication process transparent to the controllers. Is it just HttpContext.User, or is there more setup to do?

Comment: This [walk through](http://bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0) might help - it gives a description of adding custom authentication, whilst still allowing use of the built in security

Answer (score 0):

you could override the `Init` method in `Global.asax` page and listen to the `PostAuthenticateRequest` event, the events fires after authentication so you could change whatever values you like from the form authenticate cookies and inject your own